# Scalar product of 2 vectors.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, contest-math

The scalar product of two vectors $\overrightarrow u$ and $\overrightarrow v$ represented as $\overrightarrow u\cdot\overrightarrow v$ One now knows that three vectors $\overrightarrow a$,$\overrightarrow b$ and $\overrightarrow c$ such that $\overrightarrow a\cdot\overrightarrow b $ + $\overrightarrow b \cdot \overrightarrow c =0 $ Hence :

**A** $\overrightarrow c =-\overrightarrow a$

**B** $\overrightarrow b$ is orthogonal to $\overrightarrow a + \overrightarrow c$

**C** $\overrightarrow b = \overrightarrow 0$ or $\overrightarrow a + \overrightarrow c =0$

**D** $\overrightarrow a$,$\overrightarrow b$ and $\overrightarrow c$ must be collinear.

**E** $\overrightarrow a$ is orthogonal with $\overrightarrow b$ and $\overrightarrow c$ is orthogonal with $\overrightarrow b$

- **My work**

If it's **A** then the answer should have been the $\overrightarrow 0$.

I think the answer is **B** because if $\overrightarrow b$ is orthogonal to the sum of $\overrightarrow a$ + $\overrightarrow c $ this leads to a scalar value which is represented as a dot with a circle around it on the cartesian system.

It's not **C** because the answer should be $\overrightarrow 0$ and not 0.

For **D** I thought for 3 vectors to be collinear they can't be orthogonal to eachother so reaching 0 isn't a possibility.

For **E** I thought you'll get 2 times the scalar value of 0 which is not what we want.

Could someone guide me to the right answer?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The question doesn't make sense, since no assumption is made about $\vec c$.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I mean that no assumption is made about $\vec c$. All that you are assuming is that $\vec a\cdot\vec b=0$.

Comment: Excuse me I forgot to add the other term. It should now make sense.

Comment: Option $C$ still does not makes sense. $\vec{a}+\vec{c}=?$

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron I've edited that as well.

Comment: @Anonymous196 Your reasonings for options $B$ , $C$ and $E$ are really concerning . They are horribly wrong. I might sound repetative , but I really do not want you to just take the counter examples at face value and stop there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct answer is $B$.

The dot product is commutative and distributive. That is $\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b}=\vec{b}\cdot\vec{a}$ and $\vec{a}\cdot(\vec{b}+\vec{c})=\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b}+\vec{a}\cdot\vec{c}$.

This is why $\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b}+\vec{b}\cdot\vec{c}=\vec{b}\cdot(\vec{a}+\vec{c})=0$ This leads to the conclusion in option $B$ becasue this **IS** the definiton of orthogonality of two vectors.

For $A$ you can take $a=\hat{i}$ ,$ b=\hat{j}$ and $c=2\hat{i}$ to disprove the claim. You say that if it was so then you get $0$. That is already given to you and it does not lead to a contradiction of any kind . That is wrong reasoning.

Your reasoning for $C$ is NOT totally correct. Most times $0$ and $\vec{0}$ in Linear Algebra means the same thing. Although as you correctly say that $0$ is the scalar $0$(That is the $0$ element of the field and $\vec{0}$ is the null vector in the vector space) . Ignore the brackets if it does not makes sense to you right now . I assume you are only familiar with high school level vector algebra and calculus(The bare minimum needed for physics).

The complete reasoning for $C$ should be like this. Let $\vec{a}=\hat{i}$, $\vec{b}=\hat{i}+\hat{j}$ and $\vec{c}=-\hat{j}$. Then you have $\vec{b}\neq \vec{0}$ and $\vec{a}+\vec{c}=\hat{i}-\hat{j}\neq \vec{0}$.

For $D$ .Let  $\vec{b}=\hat{i}+\hat{j}+\hat{k}$, $\vec{a}=-\hat{i}$ and $\vec{c}=\hat{j}$. Then these are not collinear.

For $E$ your reasoning is totally incorrect. $2\cdot\vec{0}=\vec{0}$. These are serious misconceptions on which I think you should work on. You have to come up with counterexamples which show that the claim is false.
For this again the example for $D$ suffices to show that the claim is not true.

Comment: For **E** I meant that the result will be two times the result of two orthogonal vectors which leads to null vector, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes but two times the null vector is still the null vector

Comment: Oh of course. I wasn't suggesting the opposite. I have problems to explain things. I'll try better the next time.

Comment: Look we really need to resolve the issue with your reasoning in B,C and E right now. I cannot but stress how such a misconception can stay with you for a long time if it remains unresolved. You cannot argue like this " This is represented in a different way in such and such systems and hence it is wrong". No that type of thinking is very very wrong. You have to produce counter examples if you want to disprove some claim.

Comment: I'll have my afternoon meal and then I'll think of counterexamples of my own.

Comment: @Anonymous196 It's not just about counter examples. It's about the basic things that are wrong with your reasoning. I don't think you understand the meaning of a null vector. Null vector is the equivalent of $0$ . $\vec{a}+\vec{0}=\vec{a}$ and $c\cdot\vec{0}=0$ for all scalars $c$. Your reasoning for $E$ immediately suggests your conception is wrong.

Comment: Ok, so we can assume that the null vector is a vector with absolute value 0, is this correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134343/discussion-between-mr-gandalf-sauron-and-anonymous196).

Answer (score 1):

Option **B** is obviously true.

All others are false:

**A:** Take $\vec c=-2\vec a$, for instance.

**C:** My guess is that $\vec0$ here is a typo and that it should be $0$ here. And there are plenty of examples of non-zero vectors with scalar product equal to $0$ (unless your space is $1$-dimensional).

**D:** For instance, in $\Bbb R^2$ endowed with the usual scalar product, take $\vec a=(1,0)$, $\vec b=(0,1)$ and $\vec c=(1,0)$.

**E:** For instance, in $\Bbb R^2$ endowed with the usual scalar product, take $\vec a=(1,0)$, $\vec b=(1,1)$, and $\vec c=(-1,0)$.

Comment: So for **A** in your example it would give a negative vector, correct? **C** What do you mean with type? If you mean typo: I've typed that from the math olympiad I've gotten.

Comment: I don't know what a negative vector is. And, yes, I meant “typo” (and I've edited my answer).

Comment: I meant a vector that it would become -$\overrightarrow a \cdot \overrightarrow b$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos With all due respect, I think your answer should address the misconceptions of the op and not just a few examples to solve the problem. For example, the op's reasong in option E is seriously concerning and your answer should also address that . Also the op asks for "guidance to the right answer" .

Comment: Yes, if $\vec c=-2\vec a$, then $\vec a\cdot\vec b+\vec b\cdot\vec c=-\vec a\cdot\vec b$.

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron That's a fine suggestion, but you have already done that.